# Were there any female soldiers in the Soviet army who partook in the mass rapes in Eastern Germany?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, war, women, occupations

Were there female Soviet soldiers that partook in the mass rapes in Eastern Germany?

The only source I found on any reaction of female soldiers on the mass rapes was in a testimony of a veteran:

> [YouTube: Russian veteran recalls their crimes in Germany - female telephonist laughing too](https://youtu.be/5Ywe5pFT928)

It's not an uncommon occurrence when women partake in war crimes, but it's rare when it's of a [sexual nature](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/world-politics/article/abs/female-combatants-and-the-perpetration-of-violence-wartime-rape-in-the-sierra-leone-civil-war/40294185202988F2BB263A2943A79F8B).

Is there any anecdotal or scholarly evidence of women who partook or at least aided in the rapes of German women in Eastern Germany?

Comment: There is a difference between witnessing a crime and taking part in it. Women are often a minority in an army, and may feel themselves unprotected.

Comment: Well understandable. But if someone can take delight into seeing such things, it's not out of question someone can partake in it.

Comment: Perhaps, she is laughing hysterically, because she identifies with the victim and/or believes that she could easily be the next (especially if she tried to defend the victim.) I am not necessarily saying that this is the case - there are horrible things happening in war, just giving the benefit of doubt.

Comment: You might be interested in [Svetlana Aleksievitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svetlana_Alexievich), a Nobel-prize winning author, whose major text [The Unwomanly Face of War](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VhUTDgAAQBAJ&hl=fr&source=gbs_similarbooks) deals specifically with the Soviet women during WW2.

Answer (score 6):

[Ferenc Nagy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferenc_Nagy) (*The Struggle Behind the Iron Curtain*, [1948 translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ld-xAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22The+barbarism+of+the+Soviet+occupying+forces+can+best+be+judged%22)) claims that this occurred in Hungary (so not quite Eastern Germany, though Hungary was occupied by Germany from 1944 until "liberation" by the USSR):

> The barbarism of the Soviet occupying forces can best be judged by the fact that many thousands of Hungarian men were raped or forced to unnatural excesses by Russian women soldiers. The Reds established a recreation camp near Kecskemét for more than thirty thousand sick and convalescent women members of the Soviet army and the police forces. From this camp, for instance, the Russian women banded together at night and swooped down on the surrounding hamlets, kidnapping the men and sometimes holding them captive for days. Often these abductions led to the peculiar girls hiding, not themselves, but their men in the forests and in haystacks to keep them from the disease-ridden Soviet women troops. The facts were first reported to the Swiss legation in Budapest; the results of its investigation were published by the Swiss Foreign Office in May, 1945, as a warning to the world.

---

Cecil Eby (*Hungary at War*, 1998, [p. 24](https://books.google.com/books?id=kj5O8mvmj5UC&pg=PA24)):

> When they began shipping random Hungarians to the USSR as slave laborers, Sághy decided it was time to leave. He hopped a freight train moving south toward Szeged, but near Kecskemét he was caught and arrested. His warden was a Russian female soldier who forced him to have sex with her. Afterward she turned him loose, and he escaped in the darkness.

(On p. 21, n.9 states, "Interview with Gyula Sághy (February 23, 1989).")

---

Krisztián Ungváry (*Battle for Budapest: One Hundred Days in World War II*, 1998, [2003 translation, p. 290](https://books.google.com/books?id=n9OLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT460))

> Four cases of men being raped by female soldiers are also known.

(Accompanying note states, "Interview with Szablya; communication by Vadász.")

Comment: TBH it sounds like a tall tale. The passage can also be found with few changes in a number of anti-communist texts from the 60s.

Comment: But at least the Swiss legation report does exist as such https://www.hungarianhistory.com/lib/montgo/montgo21.htm seemingly without any mention of Kecskemét though (unless it also goes by some other name). BTW said legation was very pissed at the Soviets for arresting its leadership.

Comment: N.B. that page is a "summary condensed" from their reports, so possibly they wrote more.

Comment: And the issue is mentioned there without referencing the location: "Cases have been reported where Russian women serving in the Red army or in the Russian police force have been guilty of rape. Men have been beaten up by such women for not having submitted themselves to their wishes."

Comment: Kinda odd but much better compared what I got on Quora.

Comment: @Fizz: That page you quote is simply from the book *Hungary: The Unwilling Satellite* by John Flournoy Montgomery, 1947 (pp. 239-245). As you have noted, it is a "summary condensed". Your quote from Montgomery ("Cases have been reported ...") would seem to corroborate rather than refute Nagy's account (presumably from the same Swiss report). There is no reason to believe that Nagy invented "a tall tale" or details such as the location Kecskemét (simply because Montgomery failed to explicitly mention this location in his particular summary).

Comment: The Swiss might have given credence to rumors etc. They say they conducted an investigation, but one has to wonder how much they could investigate, given that some of the legation's leadership was arrested by the GRU.

Comment: Well the newest edits, seem to be much more realistic at this point. 

Another question did those soldiers use any condoms or pregnancy preventions or did they do it raw? 
It's one thing when you rape a women and leave, quite another when you assault a man and carry his child.

Answer (score -2):

Anthony Beevor talks about exactly this in his book "Berlin". He does discuss the acts, female soldiers reactions and those of officers.

I believe the prevailing view in the Red Army was that the Germans fully deserved everything coming to them personally and their country for what had happened to the occupied USSR territories. I'm not endorsing that, or criticising that view by the way.

Comment: Can you cite the relevant passage? It would help to provide clarity and depth to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: i'm sorry but I dont have that book any more. I do recall reading it clearly, The book is still in print. I could look it up online but I'm at work and do not wish to have such subject matter in my search history

Comment: [Internet Digital Archive](https://archive.org/search?query=Anthony+beevor+berlin) reports audio and video sources for the search string "Anthony Beevor berlin". Perhaps peruse these for relevant excerpts and quotes.